# Contadores en ficheros

Tags: python, python-3.x

He creado una funcion que formará parte de un pequeño script de trabajo con ficheros pero no consigo que en esta funcion se acumulen unos caracteres que estoy identificando. Por los mensajes de error de la shell deduzco que se trata de una cuestion de variables que no están siendo identificadas correctamente.
Esto es lo que tengo de momento:

```
import os
os.chdir() #direccion del directorio de ficheros

def numero_bases(fichero):
    A = 0
    T = 0
    C = 0
    G = 0
    with open(fichero) as f:
        lineas = f.readlines()
        for l in lineas:
            if not l.startswith('>'): #esto lo he puesto para que no lea en lineas que empiezan por ('>') que son el encabezado de los registros del fichero, pero no estoy seguro si es la mejor forma para ello.
                for base in l:
                    if base  == 'A':
                        A += 1
                    elif base == 'T':
                        T += 1
                    elif base == 'G':
                        G += 1
                    elif base == 'C':
                        C += 1
        return A,T,C,G

while True:
    fichero = input('Introduzca nombre del fichero FASTA(q para salir):\n')
    if fichero == 'q':
        break
    print(numero_bases(fichero), A, T,C,G)
```

Lo que estoy obteniendo es un error de que las variables A, T, C,G no existen, pero en ocasiones obtengo, tras modificar el sitio de las variables, un resultado de 0, es decir que no está realizando el recuento.

Alguna idea de qué puede estar mal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu error real esta en el `print`, es decir en `print(numero_bases(fichero), A, T,C,G)` ya que `A`, `T`, `C` y `G` no están definidas porque son variables locales a la función, son en realidad valores retornados por `numero_bases` como una tupla. Dependiendo de como quieras la salida tienes varias opciones:

```
>>> print(numero_bases(fichero))

(5, 7, 10, 4)
```

O algo más elaborado usando `str.format` y desempaquetando la tupla retornada por la función:

```
>>> print("Recuento de bases:\n  A: {}\n  T:{}\n  C: {}\n  G: {}".format(*numero_bases(fichero)))

Recuento de bases:
  A: 5
  T: 7
  C: 10
  G: 4
```

Si quieres que la función retorne ya la cadena como resultado solo debes hacer algo como:

```
return "Recuento de bases:\n  A: {}\n  T:{}\n  C: {}\n  G: {}".format(A, T, C, G)
```

O en Python >= 3.6 también puedes usar literales de cadena formateados:

```
return f"Recuento de bases:\n  A: {A}\n  T:{T}\n  C: {C}\n  G: {G}"
```

Comment: al parecer he corregido un error al final del codigo he puesto un else: continue y me devuelve la tupla que mencionabas antes. Como cambiar el formato de salida en return como tu lo has puesto en Recuento bases:...?

Comment: @SteveJade ¿Te refieres a que la función retorne un string y no la tupla?, ¿Que al hacer `print(numero_bases(fichero))` se imprima algo parecido a lo que hago en el segundo ejemplo que te doy? ¿Como te gustaría que fuera la salida?

Comment: quiero que se imprima algo parecido al ejemplo que das tu

Comment: @SteveJade he editado la respuesta, mira al final de esta. Solo debes hacer que se retorne la cadena que quieras modificando la línea del `return` en la función.

Comment: ok muchas gracias